React Paginate npm library not working on server but fine on local
The pagination is working fine on local host npm run dev but when i run nmp start it  not showing the page numbers instead it show Previous next  in place of the page numbers.
This is how i am rendering the react paginate librabry
                previousLabel={"previous"}
                nextLabel={"next"}
                breakLabel={"..."}
                breakClassName={styles.pagination}
                activeClassName={styles.active}
                pageCount={pageCount}
                marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                pageRangeDisplayed={2}
                containerClassName={styles.pagiCont}
                onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                pageClassName={styles.pagination}
                pageLinkClassName={styles.paginationAtag}
                previousClassName={styles.pagination}
                previousLinkClassName={styles.paginationHead}
                nextClassName={styles.paginationHead}
                nextLinkClassName={styles.paginationHead}
                breakLinkClassName={styles.pagination}
                renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
              />


This is the handle click function that i am using

  const handlePageClick = async (event) => {
    setPage(event.selected + 1);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${BaseURL}/get-listings/?currency_accepted=${currencyFrom}&currency_payout=${currencyTo}&available_liquidity=${availableLiquidity}&payout_option=${payoutOption}&payin_option=${payinOption}&page_size=10&page=${
          event.selected + 1
        }&rate_sort=${sortByPrice}`,
        {
          method: "GET",
        }
      );
      const resData = await response.json();
      const PassData = resData.results;
      if (PassData.length < 1) {
        toast.warn("No data available for this Search ");
      }
      setData(PassData);

      setNoOfRecords(resData.count);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };


